# Invalid Provisioning Profile- Missing Code-Signing Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, code-signing, provisioning-profile

My App is finished and I have submitted one before but every time I attempt to go through the application loader it fails giving me the following error:

ERROR ITMS -9000 "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The Provisioning profile is invalid. [Missing Code-Signing Certificate]

Does anyone have any help. I have been working for 12 hours straight and this is tremendously frustrating, any a dive would help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/), recreate the provisioning profile (distribution profile in your case) and download it again. Make sure that the Distribution certificate is installed in your Keychain Access in order to sign apps submitted for the App Store.

Comment: you shouldn't have. this didn't solve the problem :-(