# Certificate and provisional profile issues

Tags: ios, loader

Not sure if it is Certificate but #Invalid Provisional Profile#
Here is the error:

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning
>   profile included in the bundle com.DOMAIN.APPNAME
>   [Payload/APPNAME.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate.]
>   For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

This error comes up in Application Loader for uploading/sending apps to the app store.
Need more info? Just ask! :)
Thanks for taking your time to help me about the is issue! :)

EDIT:
When I try to archive and distribute or validate in Xcode, the certificate/profile is invalid.

Comment: check this answer u may have same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697237/invalid-provisioning-profile-missing-code-signing-certificate

Comment: This is not helping me @user3614966

Comment: did u check in developer credential that ur certificate is valid on inactive status or try it by recreating the distribute certificate

Comment: I have done this zoo many times.. Can\t download Identity in Xcode ...
Know this problem? @user3614966

Comment: sorry im not getting wt ur saying

Comment: did u change ur appname after creating the app id

Comment: Yes, I think I did.
Whats the issue then? @user3614966

Comment: in my answer i have given reason for ur issues please check it

Comment: @user3614966 please let me know whether its working or not

Answer (score 0):

The AppID/BundleIdentifier identifies a unique App. BundleIdentifier means is ur App once u created an Appid with the Bundleidentifier it cannot be changed u have changed the App name after creating the Appid so the problem is the distribute certificate which u have created with appid is not same with bundleidentifier which u have changed recently. Once u create the Appid with one Bundlename it can't changed so u need to created new appid with ur new BundleIdentifier name.

Using the new Appid create the distribute certificate then it will work.

Comment: If the apps name is ex: Stig Ping.
The identifier sets to Stig-Ping.
What do I use as APPID?

Comment: its very simple while creating appid it wont take white space so thats y we using the - symbol Stig-Ping like this nothing will happen

Comment: I will check on it later, and thanks for your help :) If it works, I will :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after I changed app name, fixed it by changing back.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps carefully before submitting -

1. Your bundle id should be unique. Generate app identifier on iOS provisional portal using the bundle id. (Registering an App ID)
2. Then in the same portal, generate the provisional profile for your app.(development or distribution)
3. Download the provisional profile file and install it on xCode by double clicking.
4. Finally, generate the build (archive) and upload to iTunes connect.