# `pilot upload` fails with "Missing code-signing certificate"

Tags: cordova, fastlane

Here's the full error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning
>   profile included in the bundle com.appname.llc [Payload/AppName.app] is
>   invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution
>   Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App
>   Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

I think this started happening right after I updated cordova-ios to 4.3.0 but can't be 100% sure.

I tried creating new provisioning profile as [this one suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697237/invalid-provisioning-profile-missing-code-signing-certificate), no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to add `packageType` key to build.json.

Turns out, with cordova-ios 4.3.0, they changed the structure of the build.json file:

```
{
    "debug": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXX",
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "provisioningProfile": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "packageType": "development"
    },
    "release": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXX",
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Distribution",
      "provisioningProfile": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      "packageType": "app-store"
    }
  }
```